# Android looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The code shown uses an AsyncTask class to call a blocking process so that the UI is not blocked, and a progressbar is shown. The funny thing is that the onClick method works, but the KeyCode method doesn't. Any suggestions please?

```
    // inside the onCreate method of the activity
    .....
        ttsymbol.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
            { 
                @Override 
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
                        switch (keyCode)
                        {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                            new myBGtask().execute(ttsymbol.getText().toString().trim());
                            return true;
                        } 
                        return false; 
                } 
            }
        ); 
        mainPanel.addView(ttsymbol);

        //GetData button
        final Button btnGetData = new Button(this);
        // configure the button adding onClick method 
        btnGetData.setText("Get Pivot Point");
        btnGetData.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnGetData.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        btnGetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                new myBGtask().execute(ttsymbol.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        });
        mainPanel.addView(btnGetData);
    .....

    private class myBGtask extends AsyncTask {
    private String spage;
    protected Long  doInBackground(String... URL) {
        String starget;
      try {
          starget =  URL[0];
          spage = CustomHttpClient.myHttpGet(starget);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "failed to GET webpage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return (long) 0;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        String sresults;
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        sresults = scrape(spage);
        if (sresults.length() == 0 ) 
        {
            lblDATE.setTextColor( Color.BLACK);
            lblDATE.setText( "cannot find that!");
            return;
        }
        String s[] = sresults.split("\n");

        lblDATE.setText(s[0]);
        .....
    }
    }
```

error messages:

```
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:68)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.chrisdev.geturltry1.Chrisgeturltry1Activity$myBGtask.doInBackground(Chrisgeturltry1Activity.java:204)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.chrisdev.geturltry1.Chrisgeturltry1Activity$myBGtask.doInBackground(Chrisgeturltry1Activity.java:1)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-07 20:10:32.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     ... 4 more
09-07 20:10:32.619: WARN/ActivityManager(69):   Force finishing activity com.chrisdev.geturltry1/.Chrisgeturltry1Activity
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? What it has to do with `looper.prepare()`?

Comment: sorry forgot the error messages!

Comment: Post the error message after removing the toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because `Toast.makeToast()` is called from background thread. You can't do it in `doInBackground()` instead return value from this method describing exception and show toast in `onPostExecute()` if you get this specific value.

Apparently, code in `try` block fails in one case but not another. That's different from problem with `looper.prepare()`.

Comment: I removed the Toast - same outcome. Toast is a red herring.

Comment: Are you saying that you got the same 'looper.prepare()` error message even as you removed the toast?

Comment: Restarted this morning (GMT) and everything is performing as it should, so my guess is that I did not successfully reload the app into the simulator, which would account for the results being he same!. So you are right Alex, full marks!

Answer (score 0):

handler.post(showToast);

showToast(){
 run().run{
    toast......
 }
}