# How to make a "dumb" progress bar?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
private void Load()
{
    new pbar().execute();
    //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Display.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    success = faHelper.SourceDownload(Url);
    displaystuff();
    //dialog.dismiss();
}

private class pbar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
   protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused) 
   {
       dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Display.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
       while (success == 0) {}
       dialog.dismiss();
       return null;
   }
}
```

i have this code that throws an error. i need a pbar that shows till success is = something other than 0.

```
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:145)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:80)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:76)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:101)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at com.Testapp3.Display$pbar.doInBackground(Display.java:132)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at com.Testapp3.Display$pbar.doInBackground(Display.java:1)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-06 16:34:52.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6055):     ... 4 more
```

that is the logcat im getting. i know this is something that is super simple, but it is escaping me. any advice will be appreciated. thx

updated code:

```
private void Load()
{
    new pbar().execute();
    success = faHelper.SourceDownload(Url);
    displaystuff();
}

private class pbar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Display.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        return;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused) 
    {
        while (success == 0) {}
        return null;
    }
}
```

the error went away tho, but you never see the dialog.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7340412/324625

Comment: Are you calling `Load()` from the UI thread, like from an activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because you are executing the thread which barely gets a chance to start befor it finishes.  Then after it has died you are dowloading with your helper.  You need to move the download code into the doInBackground method of the AsyncTask.

This is more along the lines of what is necessary:

```
private void Load()
{
    new pbar().execute(url);
}

private class pbar extends AsyncTask<Url, Void, Long> 
{
    private final String message = "Loading. Please wait...";
    private int success=0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Display.this, "", message, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) 
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Display.displaystuff();
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(Url... urls) 
    {
        return faHelper.SourceDownload(urls[0]);
    }
}
```

For more information please check out the [AsyncTask developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Hah, silly me, I just assumed he already understood that part!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you have to return null; if the return type is Void.

Comment: Indeed you are [correct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/676663/808940) I failed to spot the capital 'V' but there is no need to use Void class here

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking since the AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> that you actually do have to use Void for return type: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html ...

Comment: probably better to actually return the real return type form the download function so that the result is available in postexecute ...  see my update

Comment: Yes, I agree, that is better!

Answer (score 3):

In AsyncTask you should setup your UI activities including ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute/onPostExecute like so:

```
   private void Load()
   {
    new pbar().execute();

   }

   private class pbar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
           dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Display.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              dialog.dismiss();
              displaystuff();
              return;
    }

       protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused) 
       {
           success = faHelper.SourceDownload(Url);
            return null;
       }
    }
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was writing ;)

Comment: doesnt work, progressdialog never shows. see above for the updated code.

Comment: Right, you do have to put your download code into the doInBackground!